# Hosting database and accessing on Microsoft Azure cloud using visual Studio and SQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

1.I want to host a database on Microsoft Azure cloud and also want to access it from there only.
SS_WPM is my database created on cloud,showing an online connection

[image]

2. As i click on "open with visual studio"button from the azure cloud, visual studio opens from my machine, further i am not able to access my tables in my local database.

3.Tables cannot be accessed even through azure server connection via visual studio.

[image]

4.I am able to see my tables in local database.[SQL server management studio]

Comment: Are you able to create a table through Visual Studio?

Comment: The screenshots are showing some of your personal information... If you used the same login for the connection on Visual Studio and SSMS, and SSMs and VS behaves differently, there should be an issue in VS. Can you make sure if you used the same login on SSMS?